# SFTP server with third party user management system?

Tags: sftp, aws, passwd, kubernetes, google-cloud

I understand how to set up SFTP servers on Linux and create users and their passwords manually.

So basically, the users get authenticated as normal Linux users get authenticated through `/etc/passwd`. Is there any way to introduce a third party for the user and credentials management?

I am setting up the server on Google Kubernetes Engine. I see AWS provides [SFTP as a service](https://aws.amazon.com/sftp/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) and I wanna achieve something similar on GCP.

Here is what AWS is doing:
[image]

AFAIK, everything (1,2 and 4) from the above image is in place except AWS IAM and Amazon Route S3 (point-3).

I have given AWS reference just as an example. I am looking for a way to use a third party to manage my SFTP users and credentials instead of normally using `/etc/passwd`.

There are tools available like okta, gsuite, Google Cloud Identity, etc. But I am not sure how to leverage them to manage users in an SFTP server.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP will usually go into PAM (pluggable authentication modules). Your out-of-the-box PAM configuration will probably just look at `/etc/passwd` and friends, but there are PAM modules that authenticate against LDAP or Kerberos (Active Directory) instead. There's also sssd, an Identity Management daemon from the RedHat world which can look at LDAP and/or Kerberos, get the public keys from there, cache credentials in case your LDAP goes away for a couple of minutes etc.
Either way, with LDAP/Kerberos your user credentials are not on your SFTP server. PAM also has modules for generating home directories automatically on first login.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH, the suite that brings sftp, has support for [GSSAPI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface?wprov=sfla1), which defines mechanisms you are looking for. [Kereberos](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29?wprov=sfla1) can be used as an implementation. [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol?wprov=sfla1) would be another approach you can take.

Answer (score 0):

Its SO much more cost effective to run an EC2 with an SFTP server than to use AWS's SFTP service. Also not every application supports using key based authentication.